# API, json, post, enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: php, json, post

Пытаюсь наладить взаимодействие через API с приложением. Проблема встаёт из за нехватки знаний, не понимаю что делать дальше.

Вот тестовая страница http://7815671.ru/test.php алгоритм таков загружаешь фотку выбираешь фильтр для обработки и жмёшь кнопку обработать, далее выдаёт

```
{ "status":"ok","result":"http:\/\/api3-eu.neuralprisma.com\/process_direct\/12d7a9c4-f881-4c84-a259-64d495d4ee2c_us\/s_8","photo_id":"12d7a9c4-f881-4c84-a259-64d495d4ee2c_us"}
```

Если в поле "http: убрать все слеши "\" то получается что это и есть обработанная фото фильтром.

Не понимаю что дальше делать как обработать и  вывести результат.

Есть массив .JSON

http://pastebin.com/Gxdnc2Pp

Я так понимаю что ответ от сервера надо распарсить как? Уже 3 день бьюсь над задачей голова кругом.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php  пользуйтесь на здоровье

Comment: Спасибо!! В том то и дело что только изучаю всё подряд в голове каша.

Comment: Подскажите с чего хотя бы начать?

Comment: Что значит с чего начать? вы вообще или конкретно про этот вопрос? Если про вопрос, то берете `json` строку, например лажащая в переменной `$json`, пишите `$array = json_decode($json, true);` ......далее в `$array` будет лежать ассоциативный массив, с которым работаете дальше

Comment: Алексей спасибо теперь понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Для работы с `json` в `php` достаточно воспользоваться функцией **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)**, которая декодирует JSON строку.

Например, есть у вас JSON строка, лежащая в переменной `$json`.

Вы пишете:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

В результате получите ассоциативный массив, который будет лежать в переменной `$array`, с которым уже работаете дальше на ваше усмотрение.